# This algorithm Big O is true or false and why?

Tags: asymptotics

I have a doubt with this affirmation, I like to know if is true or false and why 
$$\log(n) ∈ O(n^{1/2})$$

Comment: This is true but requires proof. It's a nice exercise.

Comment: Check out CLRS 3ed page 57.